# Python Splitting string by number and space

Tags: python, arrays, string, split, strsplit

Hy, could please someone help me? I have a lot of  strings that contain addresses and i need to split them to get street name, house number and country in array.

something like this:

```
streetA 15, New York
street number 2 35, California
streetB 36B, Texas
```

into:

```
['streetA','15','New York']
['street number 2','35','California']
['streetB','36B','Texas']
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `re.compile()`:

```
import re

def splitup(string):
    match = re.search(" \\d[^ ]*, ", string)
    if match is None:
        raise ValueError("Not a valid string: %r" % string)
    street = string[:match.start()]
    number = string[match.start(): match.end()].strip(", ")
    state = string[match.end():]
    return [street, number, state]
```

For your examples, it prints:

```
['streetA', '15', 'New York']
['street number 2', '35', 'California']
['streetB', '36B', 'Texas']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.split(',')` to get country (last item) then find last space in the first item:

```
>>> l = 'street number 2 35, California'.split(',')
>>> index = l[0].rfind(' ')
>>> l = [l[0][:index]] + [l[0][index+1:]]+ [l[1].strip()]
>>> l
['street number 2', '35', 'California']
```

Comment: I don't believe this would workfor the second item -- "street number 2 35, California"

Comment: @WoLy This leaves a white space at the beginning of the last item in the list. Try this instead: `l =[l[0][:i]] + [l[0][i+1:]] + [l[1].strip()]`.

Comment: @Gabriel  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions.

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'^(.+) (\d+\w*), (.+)$')

m = regex.match('streetA 15, New York')
print m.groups()
# ('streetA', '15', 'New York')

m = regex.match('street number 2 35, California')
print m.groups()
# ('street number 2', '35', 'California')
```

Here is an [example on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yG9oA8/1).

Comment: I think regex is overkill, given that `split()` does what's needed.

Comment: @Gabriel  For string parsing, regex tends to be more clear and self-documenting.  You can give labels to the groups to make it even clearer and all of the parsing can be done in one step on a single line of code.  Take a look at the `.split()` code and how much more difficult it is to visually parse the intention of the code.  Adding further parsing requirements, even small ones, only increases the complexity, while regex can still maintain a single line of code.

Comment: regex to me is much more complex than using built-in Pyhton functions. A single line of code can be succinct and still very complex.

Answer (score 0):

@Brendan Abel solution is good, although it returns a tuple and not a list.

You can convert it to a list using the `list()` function and this will match your output:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'^(.+) (\d+\w*), (.+)$')

m = regex.match('streetA 15, New York')
result=list(m.groups())
print result
# ['streetA', '15', 'New York']
```

Comment: Why the downvote? OP said "i need to split them to get street name, house number and country in array.".

Comment: I didn't downvote but I guess it's because your answer has already been posted by Brendan.

Comment: Indeed I didn't said "that's my answer", it's just that Brendan's code returns a tuple instead of a list, and that's what the OP wants. That's ridiculous.

Comment: Some people are very trigger happy with the downvotes. Here's a +1 for you.